# gramjs sending existing media

Tags: node.js, telegram

I want to send a message with gramJS to a telegram channel having a file_id or file_unique_id instead.

```
const mediaId = 'AgACAgIAAx0CT3U93QAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAA'
userbot.sendFile(-100123123123, {
    file: mediaId,
    message: "Hello there!",
    randomId: BigInt("-4156887774564")
})
```

and gramjs always tries to upload the file from my local system. In documentation it says "file can be  How can I send that file_id/file_unique id. I am logged in as a normal user, and I want not to download and reupload the media file if possible

I also tried different InputMedia with filerReference = mediaId, this also does not work